# JavaScript or JQuery: get innermost element on position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the innermost element on a certain cursor position, i.e.:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I point my mouse cursor over the text, I want to retrieve the `span` tag, not the outermost `div` which is the default of JavaScript's `elementFromPoint(x,y)`.

(if it is of any help: I want to retrieve the element inside a JQuery keydown event handler)

Comment: Why don't you attach the listener event to the span element? Edit: oh, you want to get the element at mouse position when you press a key?

Comment: Yep, it is a kind of debug helper for our web testers. They should get some additional information of the current element.

Comment: question is a bit vague with limited html shown. A demo would help

Comment: See this: http://plnkr.co/edit/IYO9CVzQ11KrBbXvH2js?p=preview. Press any key when hovering over the span element. It seems to work.

Comment: What element is your eventhandler being bound to?

Comment: @cpacheco: to the document.

Comment: @ClintPowell: hmm, yeah, your script works, my ASP.NET page always returns the ASP.NET main form ... need to analyze this, thanks for the moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `keydown` event does not provide properties like `.pageX` and `.pageY`, so you cannot apply those values on `document.elementFromPoint()`.
You need to have an event listener on your `window` or `document.body` and provide the `event data` information to a more public context, so you can access that data in your `keydown` handler.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1ztf2p9b/

Comment: That's what I'm doing, however, that does not answer my question. I already have the x,y coordinates, I simply want to retrieve the innermost tag instead of the outermost one.

Comment: @D.R. That is actually default behavior, see my little example snippet.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
$('div').hover(function(element){
   element.find('span').dosomestuff();
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mspocq9h/1/

```
var hoverEleme = null;

$('*').hover(function(){ 
    hoverEleme = $(this); 
});

$(window).on('keydown', function( e ) {
    // Get hoverEleme here
    $('span').css('color', 'black');
    $(hoverEleme).closest('span').css('color','red');
});
```

Using jQuery's `.closest()` call with traverse up the element's ancestors to find the first element matching the selector, in this case the closest `span`.

Here there are no filters for what key was pressed, and it just sets the color to red so you can see it finds the one you're looking for.